# HttpRequest after form method in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm new in django, and I can't to figure out how to redirect site to main page after submit.
I read here, and in others places that I need to return HttpResponseRedirect in method.
But my form looks that:

```
@login_required
#@staff_member_required
def hero_detail_create_view(request):
    #creating by form
    form = HeroCreateModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        slugCreate = str.lower(form.cleaned_data.get('name') + "-" + form.cleaned_data.get('nickname'))
        obj.slug = slugCreate.replace(" ","")
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        form = HeroCreateModelForm()
    template_name='form.html'
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

It's creating a hero. And I need to redirect to main page after submit. 
How can I do that? I can't just add second return. I tried create new method to redirect, and put in instide this, but of course it didn't wokrs.

My form html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}

{% if title %}
  <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
{% endif %}

<form method='POST' action='.'> {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type='submit'>Send</button>

</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@login_required
def hero_detail_create_view(request):
    # creating by form
    form = HeroCreateModelForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        slugCreate = str.lower(form.cleaned_data.get("name") + "-" + form.cleaned_data.get('nickname'))
        obj.slug = slugCreate.replace(" ","")
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        return redirect("home.html")

    template_name="form.html"
    context = {"form":form}
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) after saving the object like this:

```
   obj.user = request.user
   obj.save()
   return redirect('you_main_page_url')
```

And don't call your form after saving the object

Answer (score 1):

With handling the get request, you can do the following way:

```
@login_required
def hero_detail_create_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = HeroCreateModelForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            slugCreate = str.lower(form.cleaned_data.get('name') + "-" + form.cleaned_data.get('nickname'))
            obj.slug = slugCreate.replace(" ","")
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            return redirect('your_home_page')
    else:
        form = HeroCreateModelForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form':form})
```